# Passenger on Ruby 1.8.5

Tags: ruby, mongrel, passenger, ruby-1.8

I have a situation here where one of my clients runs his production code from 2008 till date on Ruby 1.8.5 with mongrel and he denies to update the ruby/rails versions.
For the webserver, mongrel is hell out of consuming all the memory out there.
What are the issues generally would be facing if Passenger runs on 1.8.5? or do I need to forget even updating the Rails Passenger for this Client.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly advice upgrading to Ruby 1.8.7, and then running Rails Passenger. Making the jump to 1.8.7 shouldn't be a problem, and 1.8.7 is what Rails Passenger uses with REE(Ruby Enterprise Edition).